# How to draw bidirectional graph in Graphviz ordering levels by distance from some specified node (BFS order)

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a graph in a form of an adjacency list. I want to draw it vertically and specify the root to be `AA`. I want to order the nodes in the levels by their BFS distance from the node `AA` (so in this case `AA` is on lavel 0 alone, `JW HX MA KO` are on level 1 etc...). How do I do that? Is there any automatic way? I don't want to specify levels manually by `{rank=same; JW; HX; MA; KO;}`...

The graph is below:

```
strict graph {
    NV -- {ZV CG YB HX OY};
    NU -- {DA MA OA DK};
    VU -- {PS FX};
    JW -- {AA MD};
    RI -- {OY DG};
    DG -- {TG RI DF EV KW};
    PH -- {KW OW LT LZ};
    KZ -- {ET QV CK MS};
    IX -- {TS DO};
    MS -- {LZ KZ};
    IL -- {DO ET};
    EJ -- {AV JY};
    DK -- {NU CG};
    YB -- {NV PS};
    OA -- {YA NU};
    DA -- {NU RG};
    KO -- {AA TG};
    RG -- {DF DA ZV MD LB};
    MA -- {AA NU};
    OW -- {DO PH};
    KW -- {DG PH};
    DO -- {IX IL CZ OW};
    DF -- {RG DG};
    TG -- {DG KO};
    LB -- {RG FX};
    HX -- {AA NV};
    GB -- {AV XK};
    CG -- {DK NV};
    LT -- {AO PH};
    FX -- {LB HY VU};
    ET -- {IL KZ};
    CK -- {UX KZ};
    LZ -- {PH MS};
    YA -- {JY OA};
    TS -- {NO IX};
    NO -- {TS};
    XK -- {GB};
    PS -- {EV VU YB};
    AA -- {JW HX MA KO};
    MD -- {JW RG};
    JM -- {QV HY AO};
    AV -- {EJ GB};
    AO -- {JM LT};
    JY -- {YA EJ};
    OY -- {NV RI};
    UX -- {CZ CK};
    HY -- {JM FX};
    EV -- {PS DG};
    CZ -- {UX DO};
    ZV -- {NV RG};
    QV -- {JM KZ};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **dot** on its own can't produce the graph you want.  **Dot**'s ranking algorithm is (almost) based on *longest path* instead of *shortest path*.
However, the Graphviz system also includes the **dijkstra** program (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dijkstra.1.pdf) that will annotate a graph with a **dist**ance attribute an a **prev**ious node attribute (along the shortest path)  (Although the *dijkstra* algorithm differs from the *BFS* algorithm, I expect the results to be the same.)
As **dot** does not allow explicitly setting ranks (except for **source** and **sink**, some extra coding is needed to:

- create subgraphs for the **rank=same** groupings
- identify the "top" node - **rank=source**
- set **constraint=false** on most edges (bidirectional graph causes dot to confuse ranks
- set **constraint=true** on those edges that comprise shortest paths

The programming is done in **gvpr** (http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf), also included in the Graphviz package.
The **gvpr** program `shortestPath.gvpr`:

```
E{
  $.constraint="false";    //  default to false
}
BEG_G{
  graph_t  SG;
  node_t   aNode;
  edge_t   anEdge;
  int D, oD, i, cnt;
  float Df;
  string tmpStr,  pref="__addedSubg__";
  string sameRank[], tok[int];
}
N{
  if (hasAttr($, "dist") && $.dist!=""){
    Df=(float)$.dist;
    D=(int)Df;       // convert to integer
    $.Dist=D;
    sameRank[D]=sprintf("%s %s", sameRank[D], $.name);
    //print("//  dist ", $.name, "  ", $.dist, "  ", D, "  ", sameRank[D]);
    if (hasAttr($, "prev") && $.prev!=""){
      aNode=node($G, $.prev);
      anEdge=edge(aNode, $, "");
     // anEdge.constraint="true";
    }
  }
}
BEG_G{
}
N{
    if (hasAttr($, "prev") && $.prev!=""){
      aNode=node($G, $.prev);
      if ($.Dist==aNode.Dist+1){
        anEdge=edge(aNode, $, "");
        anEdge.constraint="true";
      }
    }
}
END_G{
  for (sameRank[D]){
    print("//  D  SAME ", D, "  ", sameRank[D]);
    tmpStr=sprintf("%s%i", pref, D);
    SG=subg($G, tmpStr);
    if (D==0)
      SG.rank="source";
    else
      SG.rank="same";    
    unset(tok);
    cnt=tokens(sameRank[D], tok);
    for (tok[i]){
      aNode=node($G, tok[i]);
      subnode(SG, aNode);
    }
  }
}
```

And a (Linux) command line of:

```
dijkstra -p AA autoRank0.gv|gvpr -c -f shortestPath.gvpr|dot -Tpng >oo.png
```

Giving:
[image]